# What is core java and advanced java

Tags: java, terminology

I hear most of the the time people say core java and advanced java.I like to know what is the difference between core java and advanced java.

Comment: Never heard of that. What people?

Comment: These terms are only used in books, and usually not very good books. The terms themselves are entirely subjective, and generally meaningless.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent & @skaffman it's not rare in job offers (at least I've seen it)

Comment: @Bozho I can imagine what core means (and thus what advanced means, everything that is not in core) but this is for me a cluelessness indicator, there is officially no such thing.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent quite correct, but when one sees such a thing in a job description, he wants to see if he's eligible. The fact that the author of the job offer has taken an arbitrary "term" means he hadn't asked a question on SO "Is there officially Core Java?" :)

Answer (score 12):

"Core Java" is AFAIK not an official, well-defined term. It is, however, the title of a book from Sun that introduces Java as a language and the most important parts of the Java SE Standard API - and that's probably what most people think of when they hear the term.

"Advanced Java" would then be everything that goes beyond that - most importantly the APIs defined in Java Enterprise Edition, i.e. Servlet programming, Web Services, the Java Persistence API, etc.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Core Java book and making sense otherwise too. The book (http://www.horstmann.com/corejava.html) is actually pretty decent, from what I remember of it. (It consists of two volumes: #1 Fundamentals and #2 Advanced Features – so, actually advanced is core too? ;)

Answer (score 9):

I don't who "people" are, but they might refer to Java SE as "core" and Java EE as "advanced".

Answer (score 4):

There is no clear distinction. I'd say "Core Java" is:

- `java.lang.*`
- `java.util.*`
- `java.net.*`
- `java.io.*`

Everything else is "advanced".

Comment: Just added it, skaffman.  Good catch.  Dependencies make java.lang, java.io, and java.util one big package.

Answer (score 2):

**Basic difference between core and advance Java:**

**Core Java:** J2SE

**Advance Java:** J2EE

Answer (score 1):

Here's one explanation listed based on *this* user's perspective at [**WikiAnswers - What is the difference between core Java and advanced Java?**](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_difference_between_core_Java_and_advanced_Java) You can read more, if you like.

> Core Java has to do with the basic package of Java objects that are typically used for general desktop applications. These objects come in the 'Standard Edition' of Java
>
> Advanced Java could actually refer to any advanced topic having to do with Java programming-- and there are many.

As noted in the comments, there is no *concrete* definition of what the differences are, (*or even what the definition of the term Core Java*) the term can be used loosely and the definition will be vary from user to user.

Comment: This doesn't sound official at all.

Comment: My knowledge of Swing is very shaky, and to me is "advanced java", whereas to me the servlet API is trivial, and very much not advanced. It's all subjective.

Comment: Not to mention I've had hard time with `io` after I've used Struts1 (a long time ago), for example.

Answer (score 1):

Probably "core Java" is Java SE, in other words the stuff available in the standard edition (no Java EE, no Java ME).

Advanced is then the rest!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider Core Java as a Basic Java language API/Classes/Lib that is Java SE.
Advanced Java is written on top of Core Java beyond Core Java Classes and Library.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge the basic difference between the core java and the advanced java is that,
Core java is used for developing general java application where as Advanced java is used for developing the web based application and enterprise application.
Core java is having the concept of Java Fundamentals,Applet,Swings,JDBC,JavaBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Core java is basic java e.g. `String`, `Collection`, `Thread`, etc. Advanced java is probably j2ee stuff.

Comment: you can also include collections,file IO,applets,Swing etc. in core Java, while Socket Programming, RMI, Sevlets, JDBC etc. in Advanced Java... I think this is an endless debate.. highly depends on which way you think about JAVA...

Answer (score 0):

What is it called if you work with extremely complex algorithms that only use Core Java?   Advanced Core Java Programming?

What if you write very simple Java EE apps? Simple Advanced Java Programming?

I would say Core Java is Java SE.  Advanced Java is anything that is more complex than simple programming.  Some strictly Core Java programs may be Advanced Java.  Some Advanced Java may use more than just Core Java.

To say that Advanced Java == Java EE and Core Java == Java SE seems silly to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is ***no core and advanced java in java world***... we have only **j2se,j2ee and j2me.**  The fundamentals concepts of java which deals basically with oops concepts and their implementation in language can called core java. Advanced java means to gain brief knowledge on any particular java concept.

Those who knows Advanced java they knows Core java but not vice-versa

Thanks